# Converting 2D array into 3D?

Tags: c

Is this a proper way of taking half of 2D array and "converting" it to a 3D array?

```
#define CH_2D (6)
#define CH_3D (3)

float   w_2d [65*CH_2D][2];
float (*w_3d)[65][CH_3D][2] = (void *) w_2d;
```

Will this access the right elements of original `w_2d`:

```
for(int i=0; i<65; i++) 
{
   for(int j=0; j<CH_3D; j++)
      for(int k=0; k<2; k++)
         float temp = (*w_3d)[i][j][k]; 
}
```

Comment: This might be helpfull: [Aliasing of C-language arrays](http://tamivox.org/redbear/array_alias/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have 2 issues with your attempt.

> Is this a proper way of taking half of 2D array and "converting" it to a 3D array?

It's not. You are dereferencing pointer with type `float[65][3][2]`, when the actual type is `float[390][2]`, which is strict aliasing violation. To get around this issue, you need to put your C compiler to non-standard mode by disabling strict aliasing, or just rewrite your code to not do that.

> Will this access the right elements of original w_2d:

It depends on how you have stored your data on the original array. It might work if the data is stored in order similar to:

```
float[2][65][3][2]
```

However, from your `w_2d` declaration is suspect that your data is arranged like:

```
float[65][6][2] 
      or
float[6][65][2]
```

In this case I doubt that you will get the elements you want.

Comment: Are things much different in C++?

Comment: @Danijel As far as I know, these rules are the same in C++.